# Why does the return value from the tk.Canvas find_withtag method become empty?

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

The same tag specific to the image object in Canvas and the text object attached to it was added. If the find_withtag method is executed with that tag as an argument, the return value will be empty.
However, the return value is not always empty.

In the list, two objects with tags of '000330208100' and '112233445566' can be found respectively, but find_withtag () returns empty when '112233445566'.
Since the ID cannot be acquired normally from the tag, even if a tag is given as an argument to the delete method or move method, it will not operate normally.

The tag to be operated is stored in self.drag.

```py
tag_list = list()
for weight in self.canvas.find_all():
    t = [ (weight,tags) for tags in self.canvas.gettags(weight) if self.drag_obj in tags]
    tag_list.append(t)

print(tag_list)
print(self.canvas.find_withtag(self.drag_obj) )

self.canvas.move(self.drag_obj,dx,dy)
```

Normal return

```py
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [(3, '000330208100')], [(4, '000330208100'), (4, '000330208100name')]]
(3, 4)
```

Abnormal return

```py
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [(13, '112233445566')], [(14, '112233445566'), (14, '112233445566name')]]
()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use integers as tag values. When you use a tag that looks like an integer, and then use that number in other canvas methods, the canvas will assume the value is an id rather than a tag.

From the [canonical documentation of the tk canvas widget](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm):

> Each item may also have any number of tags associated with it. A tag is just a string of characters, and **it may take any form except that of an integer**
>
> ...
>
> When specifying items in canvas widget commands, **if the specifier is an integer then it is assumed to refer to the single item with that id**. If the specifier is not an integer, then it is assumed to refer to all of the items in the canvas that have a tag matching the specifier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As you pointed out, I used integers in tags.